# How do I use an if statement correctly?

Tags: c#

I am not able to get this to run, because of the 1st line in the `if` statement. I am sure something needs to be converted, but I am not sure what.

#### My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace xx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
           string userInput;
            Console.Write("what number do you choose: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userInput > 100)
                Console.WriteLine("I hate myself");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("I love myself");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not being forced into a statically typed language such as c# for a class or something, might I recommend starting your programming experience with a language such as Ruby or Python to ease the transition from Engrish?

Comment: I think it's healthy to start with static types. It means the compiler can help you. Dynamic typing is great, but has its own more subtle pitfalls (e.g. runtime failures in cases you might not have tested)

Answer (score 18):

userInput is a string, and you're trying to compare it to an int (100). The user input needs to be converted to an int first.

```
int i;

// TryParse() returns true/false depending on whether userInput is an int

if (int.TryParse(userInput, out i))
{
    if (i > 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I hate myself");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I love myself");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid number.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `if (Int32.Parse(userInput) > 100)`
You're trying to compare a string returned by Console.ReadLine() with an integer - that's why the compiler is cribbing.

Although a more robust approach .. now that I think of it would be to use [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

```
int parsedInt;
bool bResult = Int32.TryParse(stringToParse, out parsedInt)
```

bResult will be true only if the conversion/parse operation succeeded. This would handle rogue input. If successful, the out param contains the integer value you need.